# How to post a message in twitter in dotnet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth, windows

I want to post a message in twitter. I created a sample application using windows application in c#. Created a new user in twitter and created consumer key, consumer secret, tokens in dev.twitter link. In this application codings are working fine without any error. But not posted in twitter. In Application management Twitter, API keys having the permission Read-only, i think if we chane the permission read, write, and access direct message it will work. But i am unable to modify the permission. If i modify means the below error shown "You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before granting your application write capabilities". Then i go to twitter profile  and add the mobile number again some error shown "Sorry, we don't have a connection to your carrier yet". Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many API available on internet for integrating with twitter.

[Twitter API Integration in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828195/twitter-api-integration-in-asp-net-with-cmvc4-5)

Here is a lit on twitter with details

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

API list available for .net 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

And if you are using MVC then here is a NuGet link
 http://www.nuget.org/packages/Spring.Social.Twitter/1.0.0

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @SonerGönül the question could not be answered here. Because the API are very vast and there is no easy way to implement it.

Comment: In twitter Application Management, i can't able to select the permission Read and write. If i select means error will show "You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before granting your application write capabilities". Then i go to twitter profile and add the mobile number again some error shown "Sorry, we don't have a connection to your carrier yet". please help me to select the permission for Read and Write...

Comment: I created a test app on apps.twitter.com and set the permissions as "read and write". However, it refuses to do so and tells me that I need to register my phone number.

So I went to register my number, but it tells me that my carrier is not supported. please help me..

Comment: after registering the mobile number is it asked for verification?

Comment: Enter the mobile number in my twitter profile and submit it will show the error "Sorry, we don't have a connection to your carrier yet".

Comment: Does you app accepted by twitter?

Comment: created a new application but i cant set the permissions as "read and write".

Comment: Thanks now i registered the mobile number using android phone twitter apps..

Comment: Are you facing any problem yet?

Comment: No.Thanks your comments was very useful to me.